# How to import a python class in a file without expliciting the file that contains it (only the folder)?

Tags: python, import

I have a module named 'selection' and inside that module I have
several python files called 'enn.py', 'oss.py', (...)

Each of those files, have an implementation of the respective classes

- enn.py - implementation of ENN class
- oss.py - implementation of OSS class
- cnn.py - implementation of CNN class
- and so on ...

I want to use the import

```
from reduction.selection import OSS
from reduction.selection import ENN
```

but it only works if I use:

```
from reduction.selection.oss import OSS
```

How can I do that. I can't just create a file reduction.py because
I have over 10 selection techniques and the file would be too big.
Is there any way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `selection/__init__.py`, you can import all the classes you want to be importable directly via the `selection` module:

```
from oss import OSS
from enn import ENN
from cnn import CNN
<etc>
```

Then you should be able to import `OSS`, `ENN`, etc directly from `reduction.selection`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `__init__.py` file in the `selection/` directory to import all the classes there.